# service worker cache failing

Tags: javascript, caching, service-worker, progressive-web-apps

I'm developing a progressive web application with the intention of caching all assets to be used offline. Here's my service worker

```
    self.addEventListener('install', function(e) {
        e.waitUntil(
           caches.open('default-cache').then(function(cache) {
              return cache.addAll([
                 '/',
                 '/index.html',
                 '/bundle.js',
                 '/libraries/p5.dom.min.js',
                 '/libraries/p5.min.js',
                 '/libraries/p5.sound.min.js',
                 '/sound/spokesm4v.mp3',
                 '/css/flexboxgrid.min.css',
                 '/images/icon-192.png',
                 '/manifest.json',
            ])
        }).then(function() {
            return self.skipWaiting();
        }));
    });

    self.addEventListener('activate', function(e) {
        e.waitUntil(self.clients.claim());
    });

    self.addEventListener('fetch', function(e) {
        e.respondWith(
            caches.match(e.request).then(function(response) {
                return response || fetch(e.request);
            })
        );
    });
```

Regardless if I'm online or not, the service worker fails to cache some assets (in this case bundle.js) and breaks my cache-first system, even though I log a success message upon registering the worker.

https://postimg.org/gallery/2yo1ig35y/

Comment: Like justmarkup, I am not getting any error :( However you are missing a semicolon after returning `cache.addAll`. Also, service worker registration and installation are separate, so the successful registration message does not mean the service worker installed & cached resources. Just FYI.

Comment: Which browsers are you testing on?

Comment: I am testing on desktop and mobile chrome

Answer (score 1):

I don't see the problem that caching fails for bundle.js but when opening coloursel.io I can see in the console that there is a JavaScript error in your sw.js "Uncaught ReferenceError: event is not defined at sw.js:27"

If you change

```
self.addEventListener('fetch', function(e) {
    e.respondWith(
        caches.match(event.request).then(function(response) {
            return response || fetch(event.request);
        })
    );
});
```

to

```
self.addEventListener('fetch', function(event) {
    event.respondWith(
        caches.match(event.request).then(function(response) {
            return response || fetch(event.request);
        })
    );
});
```

the Service Worker should work as expected.

Comment: Great catch, but that was me trying to solve my problem by changing  parameters around which is what you saw. I guess I forgot to change it back. The main problem with the bundle caching happens probably once out of every ten or so landings to the page and it is extremely hard to replicate the cause. It's great that it cached for you but that means that you are one of the lucky instances where it resolves.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use [sw-precache](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/sw-precache) should be easier

Comment: Suggesting a library is perfectly fine, but that being the only thing in the answer does not answer OP's question at all.